# Function to protects rows doesn't work for multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which helps me to protect rows according to the date in Column A. If the date shows yesterday then the whole row becomes protected on open, and all the rows with dates before yesterday. The problem is, that though it should work for several sheets, it works only for the first mentioned sheet (GIDER). Could you please advise anything to make it work for several sheets?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = ['GIDER','ORTAK_KASA','PERSONELextra']; // put the names of the sheets you want to run the script
  
  sheetNames.forEach(name=>{ 
         var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
         var dateRange = sh.getRange(6,1, sh.getLastRow()-2, 1);
         var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
         var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "MM/dd/YYYY");
         var protectRow;
         //check if date is less than the current date
         for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
            if(val[i][0]>=curDate){ 
            protectRow = i;
            break;
            }
         }  
        var protection = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
       //If protection exists, update else add new one.
       if(protection.length > 0){
         var range = sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 18);
         protection[0].setRange(range);
       }else{
       sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 18).protect();
       }                          
  });
}
```

Comment: This `"MM/dd/YYYY"` should probably be this `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: As for this comment, could you tell me what is the difference between using small letters and capital letters in the date? Actually, I need the format dd.mm.yyyy (with commas), but I never could make this function work with this format... So I use an additional column with MM/dd/YYYY format:)

Comment: Look at it carefully and check the documentation for Utilities.formatDate();

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html Here it is shown that the month is always written with capital letters, day and year are small letters. And it doesn't depend on the place of the month (left or middle). However, there is no explanation why... Okey, let it be like that as an axiom:)

Comment: In your code the Ys are capitalized

Comment: If you want to compare dates as strings, you should order year, month and day differently, like `yyyy/MM/dd` (for example, in your case `10/10/2020 >= 02/03/2021`, would be true, even though the latter is the later date). Also, it doesn't make sense that this works in some sheets and not on others. My guess, for what it's worth, is that you think that's the case because the dates in the working sheets don't suffer the problem I mentioned at the start of my comment (maybe they are all from current year?). In order to clarify this, can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to use `>=` here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
            if(val[i][0]>=curDate){ 
            protectRow = i;
            break;
            }
         }
```

Then you should be using new Date().valueOf() or new Date().getTime() so that you can compare them numerically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Cooper, but I couldn't get, is it the decision for my problem? I mean, this functions works, but only for the first sheet listed in square brackets. I tried to put new Date().valueOf()  instead of  new Date() (Is that the right place?) and the function didn't work at all. If I used it wrongly, could you help me with the right place to make a change, please?

Comment: You must realize `>=` suggest a numerical comparison and you can do that with strings.  Check you favorite javascript reference.

Comment: I am sorry, but what is my favorite javascript reference? :))) I think I must say that I am new to scripting)

Comment: What ever you wish it to be.